Iterate through an associative array with a nested array
I have a Multidimensional Associative Array containing a parent page with a position number related to each subpage. I am trying to save time by dynamically running through each array to write the same line of code for each subpage.
$page = array(
                "content" => array(0, 3, 1, 2),
                "users" => array(17, 5, 16),
                "settings" => array(5, 15, 10)
                );

    foreach ($page as $parent => $ary){
        foreach ($ary as $position){
            $return = $submenu[$parent][$position]; 
        }
    }

I need it to output the following:
$submenu['content'][0];
$submenu['content'][3];
$submenu['content'][1];
$submenu['content'][2];
$submenu['users'][17];
$submenu['users'][5];
$submenu['users'][16];
$submenu['settings'][5];
$submenu['settings'][15];
$submenu['settings'][10];

Everything I have found regarding multidimentional arrays involves a nesting foreach loops but that doesn't get the proper result. I am fairly new to PHP but from what I can tell, it appears that when nesting foreach loops the initial $parent key from the first loop becomes inaccessible to the second loop.
One thought I had was to create one long combined array, but it just returns [0] => array() [1] => array() I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thank you
I tried with something like this:
foreach ($page as $parent => $ary){
        $bigarray = array($parent => $ary)
        foreach ($bigarray as $parent => $position){
            $return = $submenu[$parent][$position]; 
        }
    }


The "parent" array key is accessible on the "child" array without any issues. You just have to output the simple quotes and the '$' signs to get the output that you want:
<?php

$page = [
    "content" => [0, 3, 1, 2],
    "users" => [17, 5, 16],
    "settings" => [5, 15, 10]
];

$return = '';

foreach ($page as $parent => $ary){
    foreach ($ary as $position){
        $return .= "\$submenu['$parent'][$position];" . PHP_EOL; 
    }
}

echo $return;


Note that I escaped the $ signs so it's treated as a simple chat instead of denoting that the string next to it is not interpreted as a variable.
Look the output here:
https://3v4l.org/P4494
